# Can I remove all images of WP 1 Slider gallery in code and replace it with my custom field gallery in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to use WP 1 Slider gallery plugin for listing my Custom Field gallery, but I had to set all gallery fields in code, not in the Administration. Is that even possible? My first idea was to update SQL tables, but I only found ID of gallery in the table wp_posts. Can not found all images updated for that gallery.

[image]

Shortcode of my plugin : `[wp1s id="202"]`

Comment: please share some code that you tried to achieve.

Comment: I do not have code, cause everything I did for now is in adminitration... do not even know if I had to look for all records of Test Gallery in Table, or exis some way how to delete all records in php and set with new one

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: I installed plugin wp 1 slider. Then I created some test gallery in there with few images. But mi problem is that I need this plugin due to functionality for my Custom Field gallery. Unfortunatelly, I do not know, how to set all gallery fiedls from => Custom field to my created Test Gallery in Wp 1 SLider...

Comment: You need to do custom code instead of gallery plugin.

Comment: I also think about that option , thanks

Comment: if you are not professional then hire someone would be easier.